# SQL find and replace text

Tags: sql, wordpress, replace, find

I'm working on updating an existing wordpress database and everything is going smoothly. However, the links are still directing to the old site. Is there any way to use a loop or something to run through every record and update http://OLD_URL.com to say http://NEW_URL.com?

I might just be too lazy to manually do it but I will if it comes down to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually run a couple of quick commands in phpmyadmin and I'm done. Here's a blog post that discusses this exact issue: http://www.barrywise.com/2009/02/global-find-and-replace-in-wordpress-using-mysql/ I would read this first: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL to make sure all your bases are covered first.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update links in a particular table you can use the query like below:

```
UPDATE TableName 
SET URL = 
        CASE 
            WHEN URL = 'http://OLD_URL.com' 
            THEN 'http://NEW_URL.com 
            ELSE URL
        END    
FROM TableName
```